# How can I perform business/programming/mindmap 'modeling' in 3d?

Tags: modeling, 3d-modeling

Are there any possibilities of modeling in a 3d environment? Not in a Maya or 3d studio MAX way (which I do not have any experience with), but in a UML diagram software kind of way..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, there's no reason you couldn't arrange a UML diagram in 3D. In reality, you'd almost certainly lose more than you gained by doing so. A 3D environment works well when you're representing physical objects, and people can relate to the dimensions well. In the case of UML, however, item placements are nearly arbitrary to start with, so extending into a third dimension doesn't really gain anything.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I meant adding 'objects' in a UML software kind of way. Then relating them in a 3d environment. What I hope for is that the objects have a 'wired' connection of some sort, further then that they are in no way related to UML.

Comment: Then tag this 3D mindmap or something, and move it to SuperUser.